# Mathematica equations returning true instead of solving ODE?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I want to solve a system of two ODEs using mathematica's DSolve function. Here is what I have written down:

```
DSolve[{x'[t] == 0.02*x - .00004*x*y, y'[t] == .0004*x*y - .04*y, 
  x[0] == 500, y[0] == 200}, {x[t], y[t]}, t]
```

But for some reason it just keeps telling me that the equations return true and I shouldn't have that in my syntax, and it won't solve it. Not sure why this is happening or how to fix it.

Comment: Usually "True" means you used x[t]=something once instead of x[t]==something and MMA is remembering that. Restart to clear that. Still problems. You are using both x[t] and x, y[t] and y. If I make those x[t] and y[t] I get errors about K[1]==x[t] not being a valid limit of integration. Decimal points in DSolve sometimes cause problems and if I replace all those with exact fractions I get warnings about inverse functions and to use Reduce, which I've never found documented, and I get {} for an empty solution. If I try NDSolve I get what look like two well behaved curves. Try each of those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Prolbmes:

> DSolve::dvnoarg: The function x appears with no arguments. >>

You should place `x[t]` instead of `x` in equations.

> NIntegrate::nlim: K[1] = x[t] is not a valid limit of integration. >>

You should use numerical solution because there is problem with analytical.

## Solution:

```
s = NDSolve[
  {
   x'[t] == 0.02*x[t] - .00004*x[t]*y[t],
   y'[t] == .0004*x[t]*y[t] - .04*y[t],
   x[0] == 500,
   y[0] == 200
   }, {x, y}, {t, 0, 100}]

Plot[{Evaluate[x[t] /. s], Evaluate[y[t] /. s]}, {t, 0, 100}]
```

## Result:

[image: solution.png]